# How to use Model data in String.Format?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to display every images in specific folders based on the folder name which equivalent to `Model.Id`.

```
@foreach (var imgPath in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/menu/" + Model.Id), "*.jpg"))
   {
         var img = new FileInfo(imgPath);
         <img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/menu/449/{0}", img.Name))" />
   }
```

In the last line, `449` is the folder name. How can I use `Model.Id` to replace 449? I'm not sure how to do that using `String.Format`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@foreach (var imgPath in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/menu/" + Model.Id), "*.jpg"))
   {
         var img = new FileInfo(imgPath);
         <img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/menu/{0}/{1}", Model.Id, img.Name))" />
   }
```

With `string.Format` you use numeric placeholders that match the position of the parameter included after the string. {0} is the 1st parameter, {1} the second and so on.

Comment: Ha! It's simple as that! Thank you so much! :D

Comment: @jenna_3108 -  Glad it worked. Please consider accepting an answer (see [How to accept SO answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)) once the 15 minutes period has expired.